# RTK: How to invalidate cached data in response to an update?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to invalidate cached data with RTK Query. But somehow it does not work for me. I want to fetch the ProfileList again, if the updated profile ID (in my case cognitoID) is in the ProfileList. I can guarantee that the arg.id (which represents the cognitoId) is passed correctly to the updateProfile function and that the cognitoId is included in the ProfileList response.

The invalidation works if I opt for a less granular option via `provideTags: ["Profile"]` and `invalidateTags:["Profile"]`, but fails with the setup below.

```js
function providesProfileList(resultsWithIds, tagType) {
  return resultsWithIds
    ? [
        { type: tagType, id: "LIST" },
        ...resultsWithIds.map(({ id }) => ({
          type: tagType,
          id: resultsWithIds.cognitoId,
        })),
      ]
    : [{ type: tagType, id: "LIST" }];
}

export const idApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "idApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${localStorage.jwtToken2}`);

      return headers;
    },
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Profile"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
     getProfileListViaId: builder.query({
      query: ({ page, placeID, filter, search }) => ({
        url: `users?limit=9${page ? `&offset=${page * 9 - 9}` : ""}${
          placeID ? `&place=${placeID}` : ""
        }${filter && filter.length ? `&${filter}` : ""}${
          search ? `&search=${search}` : ""
        }`,
        method: "GET",
      }),

      providesTags: (result) => providesProfileList(result.data, "Profile"),

      transformResponse: (response) => {
        const obj = {
          data: response.results,
          pageCount: Math.ceil(response.count / 9),
        };

        return obj;
      },
      async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        dispatch(showLoading());
        queryFulfilled.then(
          (res) => {
            dispatch(hideLoading());
          },
          (err) => {
            dispatch(hideLoading());
          }
        );
      },
    }),
    updateProfile: builder.mutation({
      query(data) {
        const { id, body } = data;
        return {
          url: `users/${id}/`,
          method: "PATCH",
          body,
        };
      },

      // Invalidates all queries that subscribe to this Profile `id` only.
      // `getProfileList` *might*  rerun, if this id was under its results.
      invalidatesTags(result, error, arg) {
        console.log(arg.id);
        return [{ type: "Profile", id: arg.id }];
      },
    }),
    
  }),
});

export const {
  //Profile
  useGetProfileListViaIdQuery,
  useUpdateProfileMutation,
} = idApi;
```

I am happy for any hint?

Comment: What is most apparent here is that you have `tagTypes: ["Place"],`, but are using the `"Profile"` tag everywhere. Does fixing that fix it?

Comment: @phry thanks for the hint. my fault. Basically, the error was never so in the my code and came rather through the process of preparation for stackoverlow post.

Comment: Generally this looks good and you are doing it the right way. I assume there would be a typo somewhere. Add console.log statements throughout all your `invalidatesTags` and `providesTags` functions and compare those.
There is an addition to the DevTools coming up for that, maybe you can also compile those yourself and already use them: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/pull/750#issuecomment-869586407

Comment: Thanks! I will do it with console log. The devtool extension looks like a cool feature for RTK Query. Is there a time plan when it is officially released?

Comment: They are talking about that in the issue - probably about a month, since there is generally a major overhaul of the devtools going on that has to be finished before a new version.